# Project reference not working

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity

I am developing an n-tier structure with a Data Project, Models Project, Service Project, and Web Project but project references are not working as expected.

I have added a reference in the data project to the models project, but I get "type or namespace 'Models' does not exist in the namespace WWJ.  Even more oddly, when trying to create a 'using' statement at the top of my WWJEntities.cs (in the data project), not only does it not show WWJ.Models but it shows itself (Data) and Web... How could it show Web?  The direction is opposite -- .Web references .Data, not the other way around.  I've tried removing and re-adding the referenes but it remains this way.  I'm stumped.

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKVXq.jpg)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q85zd.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the namespace of the class in image 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces and references are not guaranteed in any way to be consistent or logical.

When you type in a `using` directive, intellisense will show you available *namespaces* contained in the references assemblies, so you could have (confusing/undesirable) situations like the following:

- Assembly `Foo.dll`:

  ```
  namespace Foo { class Foo { } }
  ```
- Assembly `Bar.dll`:

  ```
  namespace Foo { class Bar { } }
  ```

And now if, `Foo` were to reference `Bar`, the only namespace you'd see when typing a `using` statement would be `Foo` because the assembly `Bar` doesn't declare any other namespace.

Make sure this isn't your case.

Comment: Thanks.  As it turns out, in the process of N-Tier-ifying my solution, I moved the default models for Identity into the Models project, which automatically renamed the namespaces :P  I should've known better when I posted but it was very late and I was so tired.  Thanks.